# how to control scrollbar in vc++ win32 api

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, winapi

basically i have a custom window which can carry other controls, let's say buttons, bitmaps, text boxes and etc, now the thing is that if the items went out of window, i mean if i tried to create like 20 button obviously it will go out of window, so i thought i should create a scroll bar to make the window scroll able. obviously you can't add WS_VSCROLL or WS_HSCROLL cause the up and down arrow of it won't be even clickable but if you tried to drag the thumb it will jump just back to the top. so i thought i better create a scroll bar with createwindow() function and control the rest of stuff.

Here is the code how i create the window itself and the scroll bar:
Code:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, "Name", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW/*WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU*/,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 1014, 585, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

 if (!hWnd)
{
  return FALSE;
}

WNDCLASSEX wcs;

wcs.cbSize          = sizeof(wcs);
wcs.lpszClassName   = szClassName;
wcs.hInstance       = GetModuleHandle(0);
wcs.lpfnWndProc     = CustWndProc;
wcs.hCursor         = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcs.hIcon           = 0;
wcs.lpszMenuName        = 0;
wcs.hbrBackground   = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcs.style           = 0;
wcs.cbClsExtra      = 0;
wcs.cbWndExtra      = 0;
wcs.hIconSm         = 0;

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcs))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

hwndCtrl = CreateWindowEx(
                     0L, // give it a standard border
                     szClassName,
                     _T("A custom control"),
                     WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|WS_BORDER,
                     0, 0, 0, 0,
                     hWnd,
                     NULL, GetModuleHandle(0), CustWndProc
                   );
ShowWindow (hwndCtrl, SW_SHOW);
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

return TRUE;
}
```

here is the code for handling its messages:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CustWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
RECT rc = {};
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
const SIZE sz = { rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top };
SCROLLINFO si;

switch(msg)
{
    case WM_MOUSEHOVER: 
        ::MessageBox(hwnd, "Enter", "Info", MB_OK); 

        return 0; 
case WM_CREATE:
    int w , h;
    w = 10;
    h = 10;
    HWND buttons;
    for(h=10;h<500; h+=35){
        buttons = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "How", WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD, w, h, 50, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)1231,NULL, NULL);
    }
    int width, height;
    width           = LOWORD(lParam);                                                   // Width Size of hWnd
    height          = HIWORD(lParam);
    Scrollbar  = CreateWindowEx(0L,
                   "SCROLLBAR",
                   NULL, // There is no text to display
                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT,
                   980,
                   47,
                   18,
                   405,
                   hWnd,
                   NULL,
                   hInst,
                   NULL
                );
    return 0;
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.fMask  = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS;
    si.nMin   = 0;
    si.nMax   = 1000;
    si.nPage  = 10;
    si.nPos   = 54;
    SetScrollInfo(Scrollbar, SB_CTL, &si, TRUE);
    return TRUE;


default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return FALSE;
}
```

as you can see there are some buttons which is automatically being created with for loop and after that the scroll bar itself is being created, now i don't know how to make it scroll down and up and so and so forth. 
All replies are welcomed

Comment: handle WM_HSCROLL or WM_VSCROLL message, and update you client area with ScrollWindow.

Comment: Not entirely obvious to everyone: [There are two types of scrollbars](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/10/129068.aspx). @Jichao's proposed solution applies to scrollbars that are attached to a window by virtue of the `WS_VSCROLL` and `WS_HSCROLL` window styles.

Answer (score 6):

A quick and dirty example:

```
case WM_VSCROLL:
{
    auto action = LOWORD(wParam);
    HWND hScroll = (HWND)lParam;
    int pos = -1;
    if (action == SB_THUMBPOSITION || action == SB_THUMBTRACK) {
        pos = HIWORD(wParam);
    } else if (action == SB_LINEDOWN) {
        pos = g_scrollY + 30;
    } else if (action == SB_LINEUP) {
        pos = g_scrollY - 30;
    } 
    if (pos == -1)
        break;
    WCHAR buf[20];
    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_POS;
    si.nPos = pos;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;
    SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
    GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si);
    pos = si.nPos;
    POINT pt;
    pt.x = 0;
    pt.y = pos - g_scrollY;
    auto hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    LPtoDP(hdc, &pt, 1);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    ScrollWindow(hWnd, 0, -pt.y, NULL, NULL);
    g_scrollY = pos;
    return 0;
}
case WM_CREATE:
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        auto hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 10, 30 * i, 250, 21, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
        wchar_t buf[10];
        StringCchPrintf(buf, 10, L"%d", i);
        SetWindowText(hEdit, buf);
    }
    RECT rc = { 0 };
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = 30 * 99 + 21;
    si.nPage = (rc.bottom - rc.top);
    si.nPos = 0;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;
    SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
    return 0;
}
```

Effect:

[image: scroll effect]

Full code: http://pastebin.com/byE1xFsb

Here is the explanation:

1. The whole height of the window should be 30 * 99 + 21. 99 is the edit count, 21 is the edit control's height.
2. The scroll range for the window should be `[0, 30 * 99 + 21 - client-area-height]`. `30 * 99 + 21 - client-area-height + client-area-height` equals to `30 * 99 + 21` which is the whole height of the window.
3. To ensure the above scroll range,

   ```
    si.nMax = 30 * 99 + 21;
    si.nPage = (rc.bottom - rc.top);
   ```

Comment: oh boy can't believe it barely worked, there are still few problems like there is a limit with scrolling, . i mean it can show around 50 or something line even if i don't have that much of item and no more, sofar i know the problem is si.nMax = 30 * 99 + 21; which tell it to be limited up to sum of 30 * 99 + 21 but there has to be something much must get the window line be used and show only that much right.  and you can't click on trackbar place itself i mean i can use the up and down arrow and can drag the thumb but can click on trackbar place itself which scroll around a page or something.

Answer (score 1):

Here an [example from microsot](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Controls/scroll-text-in-scroll-bars) that do it with text but it can be easily adapted to components of fixed height. And this article [how-to-control-scrollbar-in-vc-win32-api](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32925/Scrollable-Dialog-in-Pure-Win-API) which matches exactly the  requirements of the question and has a nice readable code.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's 5 years too late, but if anyone comes looking, I figured it'd be nice to at least have an answer to the OP's second question (as Jichao answered the original).

> oh boy can't believe it barely worked, there are still few problems
>   like there is a limit with scrolling, . i mean it can show around 50
>   or something line even if i don't have that much of item and no more,
>   sofar i know the problem is si.nMax = 30 * 99 + 21; which tell it to
>   be limited up to sum of 30 * 99 + 21 but there has to be something
>   much must get the window line be used and show only that much right.

So the early-cutoff on the window is actually due to "GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);". I found in my own projects that changing it to "GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);" and having it set the RECT after the Window was created (or resized) solved the issue.

```
//Called after Window Creation (not in WM_Create! After CreateWindowEx called!) or during Resize.
void ResetScrollbarSize(HWND hWnd)
{
    RECT rc = { 0 };
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = 30 * 99 + 21;
    si.nPage = (rc.bottom - rc.top);
    si.nPos = 0;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;
    SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
}
```

That function should do the trick. Again, the important part it to use it *after* CreateWindowEx is called and completed, so the Window has a RECT to get.

Answer (score 1):

Below is Jichao's adapted code to scroll a static with children.

```
// hStaticWnd should have WS_CLIPCHILDREN flag

#define WMU_SET_SCROLL_HEIGHT WM_USER + 100 // custom message
...
SetWindowLong(hStaticWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)&cbNewScroll);
...
SendMessage(hColumnsWnd, WMU_SET_SCROLL_HEIGHT, 500, 0); 
...
SendMessage(hColumnsWnd, WMU_SET_SCROLL_HEIGHT, 0, 0); // to turn off the scroll

LRESULT CALLBACK cbNewScroll(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_VSCROLL: {
            WORD action = LOWORD(wParam);
            int scrollY = (int)GetProp(hWnd, TEXT("SCROLLY"));

            int pos = action == SB_THUMBPOSITION ? HIWORD(wParam) :
                action == SB_THUMBTRACK ? HIWORD(wParam) :
                action == SB_LINEDOWN ? scrollY + 30 :
                action == SB_LINEUP ? scrollY - 30 :
                -1;

            if (pos == -1)
                break;

            SCROLLINFO si{0};
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            si.nPos = pos;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
            GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si);
            pos = si.nPos;
            POINT p{0, pos - scrollY};
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            LPtoDP(hdc, &p, 1);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            ScrollWindow(hWnd, 0, -p.y, NULL, NULL);
            SetProp(hWnd, TEXT("SCROLLY"), (HANDLE)pos);

            return 0;
        }
        break;

        case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
            HDC hDC = (HDC)wParam;
            RECT rc{0};
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));
            FillRect(hDC, &rc, hBrush);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);

            return 1;
        }
        break;

        case WMU_SET_SCROLL_HEIGHT: { 
            RECT rc = { 0 };
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = wParam;
            si.nPage = rc.bottom - rc.top;
            si.nPos = 0;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;

            SetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            RemoveProp(hWnd, TEXT("SCROLLY"));
        }
        break;
    }


    return CallWindowProc(DefWindowProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```