# Scrollbar reverts to previous position

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, scrollbar

I am using an auxiliary `Scrollbar` to do some manual scrolling. I use the `GetScrollInfo` API to get the track position of the `Scrollbar`. However, when scrolling ends, the track position reverts to its last set position. So, I use the `SetScrollInfo` API to set the scroll info after scroll end, but then it only updates visually after a mouse move. What can I do to fix this issue?

ScrollUtility:

```
public class ScrollUtility
{
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    [PreserveSigAttribute()]
    public static extern int SetScrollInfo(
       IntPtr hWnd,
       int fnBar,
       ref SCROLLINFO si,
       bool redraw
    );

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [PreserveSigAttribute()]
    public static extern bool GetScrollInfo(
        IntPtr hwnd,
        int fnBar,
        ref SCROLLINFO ScrollInfo
    );
}

[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCROLLINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos; // Ignored by setter

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return cbSize + " " + fMask + " " + nMin + " " + nMax + " " + nPage + " " + nPos + " " + nTrackPos;
    }

    public const int SB_HORZ = 0x0000;
    public const int SB_VERT = 0x0001;
    public const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;
    public const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
    public const int SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;

    public enum ScrollInfoMask : uint
    {
        SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
        SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
        SIF_POS = 0x4,
        SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
        SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
        SIF_ALL = (SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS)
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool setOnStartUp = true; // Track position will not update if this is false
    private bool setOnEndScroll = true; // Track position reverts to last set position if this is false, but still doesn't update visually if this is true until the mouse moves.

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (setOnStartUp)
        {
            SCROLLINFO info = new SCROLLINFO
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCROLLINFO)),
                fMask = (uint)SCROLLINFO.ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL,
                nMax = 1000,
                nMin = 0,
                nPage = 50,
                nPos = 500, // The middle of the scroll bar - just for testing
            };

            // Am I using the right handle?
            ScrollUtility.SetScrollInfo(vScrollBar.Handle, SCROLLINFO.SB_VERT, ref info, true);
        }
    }

    private void vScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        SCROLLINFO info = new SCROLLINFO
        {
            cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCROLLINFO)),
            fMask = (uint)SCROLLINFO.ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL
        };
        ScrollUtility.GetScrollInfo(vScrollBar.Handle, SCROLLINFO.SB_VERT, ref info);

        label.Text = "Track: " + info.nTrackPos;

        if (setOnEndScroll)
        {
            if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
            {
                info.nPos = info.nTrackPos;
                ScrollUtility.SetScrollInfo(vScrollBar.Handle, SCROLLINFO.SB_VERT, ref info, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `SetScrollInfo` and `GetScrollInfo` you must use `SB_CTL` instead of `SB_VERT`. The `SB_VERT` is a window's standard vertical scroll bar and you use the handle of the window. In this case you have a scrollbar control so `SB_CTL = 2` and the handle of the scrollbar

Comment: maybe you could refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094254/how-to-control-scrollbar-in-vc-win32-api/32096158#32096158

Comment: I replaced every instance of `SB_VERT` with `SB_CTL` and the scrollbar `Maximum` does not change at all with a call to `SetScrollInfo`. But the `Value` apparently does because I get an exception if I try to set it above the maximum set in the designer. (In the designer I have a maximum of 100. In the above code I set a maximum of 1000 and position of 500 -> exception).

Comment: That indeed happens. It is strange. If you do an experiment. Change the values of the scrollbar with `Maximum, LargeChange` and `Value` the control works fine **without** the need of code in `vScrollBar_Scroll`. That is strange also! It shouldn't happen. That means that the system sets the info to the control internally. Interfering with this process you are calling also `SetScrollInfo`. That maybe makes the control to return to the default values `Maximum = 100` thus giving the exception. Why do you use winapi? Use the properties of the control  `Maximum, LargeChange` and `Value` instead.

Comment: I use the WinAPI because I need to set the page size, which isn't exposed by the `ScrollBar`. I found I was able to override OnValueChanged and set the page size there (every time it is called). Dirty, but I don't know any other way.